# How to fix the issue to save data to mongodb in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I built a code to create a server with node.js, express.js and mongodb.
It's a simple code to save user data to mongodb. I tested this code with Advanced REST Client.

At that moment, the request parameters are transferred but have 0 request error when send the request with this url: http://localhost:8080/users.

server.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var port        = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var morgan      = require('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var User        = require('./user');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(morgan('dev'));

mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/mean', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Not connected to the database: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB')
    }
});

// http://localhost:8080/users
app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
    var user = new User();
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    if (req.body.username == null || req.body.username == "" || req.body.password == null || req.body.password == "" || req.body.email == null || req.body.email == "") {
      res.send("Ensure username, email and password were provided");
    } else {
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("Username or Email already exists.");
            } else {
                res.send("user created");
            }
        });
    }
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Running the server on port ' + port);
});
```

user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, unique: true }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

    var user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mean",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^2.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.7",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing a `post` request instead of a `get` request with your browser.

Also

```
var user = new User();
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    if (req.body.username == null || req.body.username == "" || req.body.password == null || req.body.password == "" || req.body.email == null || req.body.email == "") {
      res.send("Ensure username, email and password were provided");
```

You are not sending any parameters like `email` or `name`, ... in your request. So nothing can be saved in your database.

Do `post` request instead of `get` and consider adding the correct parameters in your request and everything will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I used post method in the Advanced REST Client. You can test with this url: http://localhost:8080/users

Comment: @OleksandrLesnevskyi, if you are using a `post`, are you sending the parameters `username`, `password` and `email` in your request ?

Comment: Sure. I send the parameters in json format like this. { "username":"creation", "password":"qwer","email":"test@info.com"

Comment: @OleksandrLesnevskyi, you sent the request parameters. Are you able to retrieve those parameters in your server? If not do you have an error ?

Answer (score 0):

In server.js use this code to connect to MongoDB

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mean', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Not connected to the database: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB')
    }
});
```

Mongo DB saves Object:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer was very helpful.